# Angular - toggle show/hide content not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a little show/hide content functionality in Angular, so when the menu item/tab is clicked it will show the desired content, which works fine.

Now, my problem is is that I need to initially (on page load) display the whole content of all tabs, so that all the tabs/menus are active.

And also, when clicking through the menu and if none of the tab/menu is active it should again show the whole content and make all the tabs active.

```
$scope.toggleGroup = function (group) {
        if ($scope.isGroupShown(group)) {
           $scope.shownGroup = null;
       } else {
           $scope.shownGroup = group;
        }
  };

  $scope.isGroupShown = function (group) {
    return $scope.shownGroup === group;
  };
```

Working code: [PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/26kQauLD5FbhptJIHNsF?p=preview)

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the controller to the sample below

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.showAllGroups = true;

  $scope.legend = [
      {"name":"critical"},
      {"name":"info"},
      {"name":"ok"},
      {"name":"unknown"},
      {"name":"warning"}
  ];


  $scope.availability = [
      {"name":"critical", "issue":"1111"},
      {"name":"info","issue":"2513"},
      {"name":"ok","issue":"3569"},
      {"name":"unknown","issue":"1245"},
      {"name":"warning","issue":"4598"},
      {"name":"critical", "issue":"7899"},
      {"name":"info","issue":"3265"},
      {"name":"ok","issue":"7415"},
      {"name":"unknown","issue":"0213"},
      {"name":"warning","issue":"3333"}
  ];

  $scope.toggleGroup = function (group) {
        $scope.showAllGroups = false;
        if ($scope.isGroupShown(group)) {
           $scope.showAllGroups = true;
           $scope.shownGroup = null;
       } else {
           $scope.shownGroup = group;
        }
  };

  $scope.isGroupShown = function (group) {
    if ($scope.showAllGroups)
      return true;
    return $scope.shownGroup === group;
  };
});
```

Comment: not bad...but if the user clicks inside the div it shows the whole content again, which is not very intuitive My idea was to show the whole content only on load and only if you click twice on the same menu/tab.

Comment: See updated answer. You do not need to use the onClick on the repeater any more.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
    $scope.isGroupShown = function (group) {
        return $scope.shownGroup === group || $scope.shownGroup == null;
    };

So isGroupShown() will return true for every group while shownGroup is null

UPD: 
Didnt noticed you use isGroupShown function in item click handle.
so you need another function, or just more complex expression in ng-show directive, like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="content in availability" ng-show="isGroupShown(content.name) || shownGroup == null">
    {{content.name}} : {{content.issue}}
</div>
```

[PLNKR link](http://plnkr.co/edit/2R1uMMqRtpN6hbvDP9TD?p=preview)

Comment: Your solution not working. Although it shows the whole content but then I cannot click on the individual menu :(